# How to remove/uninstall Apache Netbeans if there is no uninstall.sh?

Tags: delete, uninstall, ide

Some time ago I installed Apache Netbeans on my Linux Mint laptop, but since there are no official installers for the LTS version, I downloaded the binaries and unzipped the archive they were in.

Since I was using the binaries-version and it was not installed with any installer or through software center, can I just delete the Netbeans folder in my User directory (and other files/directories associated with Netbeans)?

There is no uninstall.sh anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Today, Apache Netbeans installs into `~/netbeans-12.0` or similar folder. It resides under your user's home directory. There is `uninstall.sh` file there. You run it and it removes the product. Are you sure you did not miss `uninstall.sh`?

Comment: Well, it was back when netbeans-11 (incubating) was released (with no official installers, thus the reason for using binary-version). I scoured through the home folder and did not find `uninstall.sh`. It might be that I deleted the netbeans folder and the script along with it. It's been almost 7 months since I asked this so I don't remember the details now. Though I've recently purged lot of junk files and used apt autoremove / autoclean and etc... So it might be gone for good.